# I want to split a value from one cell to multiple cell based on a delimitters used in the one cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Sample Image]

As per the image attached, I want to split a value from one cell to corresponding cells based on IDs mentioned in the cell.

For example, I want to distribute Product "A"'s qty 200 as 100nos to 2, 50nos to 4 and 50nos to 6. For that I mentioned as 2.100 4.50 6.50 (i.e. "2" "fullstop" "100" "space" "4" "fullstop" "50" "space" "6" "fullstop" "50). Using fullstop and space i want to split the qty to corresponding numbers. i.e, i want to split 100 to 2, 50 to 4, 50 to 6.

Please help me to do this using excel formula if it is possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible but you need to show us some efforts. How do you think this can be solved? Think of a logic and show us your attempts.

Comment: Hint you can achieve what you want with `Iferror(), Search() and Mid()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one has FILTERXML:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($C3,"."," ")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[preceding::*[1]='"&D$2&"']"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: A very clever solution though (or even *because*) not the typical xml content structure juxtaposing places and quantity values under the same node name `s` (resulting in `<t><s>2</s><s>100</s><s>4</s><s>50</s><s>6</s><s>50</s></t>` :+)

Answer (score 1):

In `D3`, formula copied across and down :

```
=IFERROR(0+MID($C3,FIND(D$2&".",$C3)+2,3),"")
```

[image]

Comment: The direct way +:)